# Comma in bibliography item of weblinks

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I need to cite few website links in my report. I am getting the reference listed in bibliography like following.

```
, , “Title of the webpage”, http://www.somesite.com, accessed: 2013-07-22.
```

How do I remove the two commas at the beginning ?

(The two fields before the two commas are `Author` and `Year` in my bibliography style. Unfortunately, the `Author` and `Year` information are not available for the website links)

The `bibtex` entry  is

```
@misc{weblinkkey,
  title = {Title of the webpage},
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.somesite.com}},
  note = {Accessed: 2013-07-22}
}
```

Note: A solution without changing the `.bst` file will be of great help. I am using a custom made bibliography style, created using custom-bib/makebst.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: I have edited my question with the answer. Thanks.

Comment: It's actually not that difficult to change the `.bst` file to handle cases of missing (or empty) `author` and/or `date` fields in an entry of type `@misc`.

Comment: An example will be of great help, as I never did it before. Thanks.

Comment: Real quick: Did you create your custom .bst file with the `custombib` (aka `makebst`) utility?

Comment: yes. I used makebst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that you've used the `makebst` utility to create your own custom `.bst` file. It looks like you've really customized the innards of the `{misc}` function. I say this, without having seen the `.bst` file, because most bibliography styles I'm familiar with -- including many created by `makebst` -- would produce something like this given the bib entry you've shown:

[image]

Notice that there are no leading commas separating any blank spaces. This is no coincidence, because `@misc` is usually BibTeX's entry type of "last resort": It has no required fields at all, and it's thus set up not to insert commas between non-existent fields. (An error message will, however, be generated if every single field is blank.)

Not having access to your .bst file, I can only suggest that you replace your current `misc` function with a more basic version, i.e., something like this one:

```
    FUNCTION {misc}
    { output.bibitem
      format.authors output
      author format.key output
      title howpublished new.block.checkb
      format.title output
      howpublished new.block.checka
      howpublished output
      format.date output
      format.issn output
      format.url output
      new.block
      note output
      fin.entry
      empty.misc.check
    }
```

(This is, incidentally, the form of the function provided by the `makebst` utility.) Of course, if you don't want certainly fields (such as `issn` and `url`) printed out at all, you would just omit the corresponding `format.<xyz> output` statements.

Comment: Let me try .. Will report after few hours due to limited internet connection. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I removed the date fields and that solved the problem. Thanks for your help.